# Loading controller component every time the page loads

Tags: angularjs

I have a component defined as such:

```
angular.
module('myHeader').
component('myHeader', {
templateUrl: 'app/headerTemplate.html',
controller: ['$routeParams', 'ArtService', 
            function HeaderController ($routeParams, Art) {
                console.log($routeParams.artPage);
                if($routeParams.artPage == 'doodles') {
                    this.artTypes = ['Doodle', 'Art'];
                } else if($routeParams.artPage == 'illustrations') {
                    this.artTypes = ['Illustrations'];
                } else if($routeParams.artPage == 'paintings') {
                    this.artTypes = ['Paintings'];
                } else if($routeParams.artPage == 'graphic_design') {
                    this.artTypes = ['Graphic', 'Design'];
                }
            }
        ]
});
```

Whenever a new page loads, the artPage parameter changes. I would like to use the new value of artTypes object everytime the page loads. Although, a console.log tells that the controller is loading only for the first time. How can I load it everytime a page is loaded?

PS: I am using Angular v1.6.1.

Comment: How about having a binding property `art` and watch the change inside component controller? The value of `art` to be set/passed in the the component - `<my-header art="scopeValueOfArt" >`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, I am new to Angular. Could you please elaborate..

Comment: Please have a look into `bindings` in angular component. You can have a binding like `bindings: {
            art: '=' // or art: '<' it depends on what binding you need
        }` and watch `$watch` that property in the controller and have your code inside it. So whenever value changes in the controller, that triggers the watch inside component